# function does not return on MacOs, but works fine on Linux and FreeBSD

Tags: macos, go, system-calls

With go1.13.6 on macOs Mojave 10.14.6, the `flockCmdMain` function from the following program does not return in the case where the timeout has reached. I've tested with the same go version on Linux and FreeBSD, and do not have this problem.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

type FlockOptions struct {
    File           string // file or dir to place the lock on
    Command        string // shell command to run
    TimeoutSeconds int
}

func main() {
    var opt = FlockOptions{}
    flag.StringVar(&opt.File, "f", "", "[REQUIRED] File or directory to lock, must already exist")
    flag.StringVar(&opt.Command, "c", "", "Pass a single command to the shell with -c")
    flag.IntVar(&opt.TimeoutSeconds, "w", 0, "Time out if the lock cannot be acquired within the specified number of seconds.(negative or 0, the default, means no timeout)")
    flag.Parse()

    if opt.File == "" {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Supply a file or directory to lock with -f <file/dir>\n\n")
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    exitCode, err := flockCmdMain(opt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    os.Exit(exitCode)
}

func flockCmdMain(opts FlockOptions) (int, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(opts.File)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    fd := int(f.Fd())

    select {
    case <-timeoutAfter(time.Duration(opts.TimeoutSeconds) * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("DEBUG: the timeout channel has fired")
        return -1, fmt.Errorf("timed out")

    case err = <-lock(fd):
        if err != nil {
            return -1, err
        }
        defer unix.Flock(fd, unix.LOCK_UN)
        cmd := exec.Command("bash", []string{"-c", opts.Command}...)
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        cmd.Run() // err discarded
        return cmd.ProcessState.ExitCode(), nil
    }
}

func lock(fd int) <-chan error {
    flockOpts := unix.LOCK_EX
    lockErr := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        lockErr <- unix.Flock(fd, flockOpts)
    }()
    return lockErr
}

// time out after d, never times out if d is zero or negative
func timeoutAfter(d time.Duration) <-chan time.Time {
    switch {
    case d <= 0:
        return make(chan time.Time)
    default:
        return time.NewTimer(d).C
    }
}
```

To trigger the problem, compile the above code to an executable called `flock`, then run the following in one terminal, which holds an exclusive `flock` on the `/tmp` directory for 123 seconds.

```
./flock -f /tmp -c 'sleep 123'
```

In another terminal, run the following, which also attempts to place an exclusive `flock` on `/tmp`, and you will see that the timeout channel firing, and then the `flockCmdMain` function hangs without returning back to `main`.

```
./flock -f /tmp -w 1 -c 'echo locked'
```

Why does the `flockCmdMain` function not return on macOs?

Comment: the `f.Close()` call is blocked by the pending `flock` call (no idea if this is intended or not). If you're only going to exit, you could simply not call `Close`.

Comment: You're right, it looks like `close` and `flock` have interesting interaction on the mac. How did you figure that out?

Comment: It was just a hunch when the goroutines were all blocked in syscalls, and confirmed by exiting directly from `flockCmdMain`. Darwin requires that Go use system libc for syscalls (using a special `libc_flock_trampoline` in this case), which probably explains the difference from other unixes (solaris may have the same issue if you want to try). I have no idea _why_ at the moment, but it at least gives you something to work around.